# ¿solucion a error al generar una alerta con javascript? error: valida_estudiante is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: php, javascript, programación-bajo-nivel

```js
function valida_estudiante(){
 if ( document.getElementById("idest").value==0 ) {
  alert("Digite el id del estudiante");
  document.getElementById("idest").focus();
  return false;
 }
 if ( document.getElementById("nombre").value==0 ) {
  alert("Digite el nombre del estudiante");
  document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
  return false;
 }
 document.form.submit();
}
```

```html
 <script languaje="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 align="center">Crear Estudiante</h1>
  <form name="form">
   <table align="center" width="400px" border="1px">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center">Ingrese datos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Identificacion:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="idest" id="idest"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Nombre Completo:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>telefono:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="tel" id="tel"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" name="Aceptar" value="aceptar" onClick="valida_estudiante()"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Puedes colocar código completo para ayudarte mejor

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CRUD</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="add_estudiante.php" title="Crear Estudiante">Crear Estudiante</a>
</br>
<a href="read_estudiante.php" title="Consultar Estudiante">Consultar Estudiante</a>
</br>
<a href="update_estudiante.php" title="Modificar Estudiante">Modificar Estudiante</a>
</br>
<a href="delete_estudiante.php" title="eliminar Estudiante">Eliminar Estudiante</a>
</br>

</body>
</html>

este es el que faltaba

Comment: ya esta todo Cesar Couoh

Comment: puedes editar tu publicación y poner el codigo completo con el javascript, quiero ver como tienes puesto tu javascript

Comment: @andres_tam tu código no tiene nada, lo reestructure y funciono bien, te recomiendo antes de publicar verifiques bien errores de sintaxis que es aparentemente el problema que tenias.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta una llave en la función "valida_estudiante"

Es buena practica la indentación de tu código para que puedas identificar rápido este tipo de errores.

Prueba esta versión corregida

```
 function valida_estudiante(){ 
        if(document.getElementById("idest").value==0){ 
            alert("Digite el id del estudiante"); document.getElementById("idest").focus(); return false; 
        }
      }
```

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, la verdad lo estoy intentando, ya que, estoy empezando en este tema, lo probe como dijiste y no me salen las alertas.

Comment: Gracias, si tienes razon, lo comprobe en otro editor, si era lo que decias, mil gracias.